# Lexical react I want to prevent users from leaving empty links

Tags: reactjs, lexical, lexicaljs

I'm trying to remove link node when user selects link formatting and leaving popup by clicking outside.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

After click new selection is present and I have no access to previous so I can't call

`editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, null);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.